# Reputation doesn't increase

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, google

Please help. I don't know if I'm exactly correct. I've used StackExchange with a Google account previously. I earned good reputation. But for some reasons I don't wanna use it now. I created another account with an yandex mail. I observe from the past few days that my reputation stays at 1, just 1, no matter what I do. I asked four questions (only one got a negative point) but it's still 1. Can I have any help? Hope everyone understands my stupidity.
P.S. : Please excuse me for my mistakes.

Comment: You should have added new log-in credentials to your previous account in order to retain your reputation. You do not gain reputation for asking a question unless it is marked up (which none of your questions on this account have been).

Comment: use the contact us link and ask for an account merger.Also, the reason your rep is at 1 is a lack of upvotes. Maybe review your questions/answers?

Comment: [You](http://superuser.com/users/582527/user11449) currently have asked 5 questions, 1 has been closed, the other 4 questions are currently open.  You have so far not performed a single actions that resulted in you gaining reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of your questions have been upvoted - unsurprisingly because most of them aren't well written.

No upvotes, no rep. You don't get rep for asking questions(unless upvoted).

Comment: You get +2 for accepting somebody else's answer on one of your questions.